# Mathematical expressions in pseudo code

Tags: python, logic, pseudocode, mathematical-expressions

I have pseudo code am trying to implement in python but I cant seem to remember what p ← 0 would mean in logic or calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually means store the value `0` on the variable `p`

In python it would be `p = 0`

Comment: True... I was really thinking math now :)

Comment: In fact, the arrow is more precise than `=` because `=` could be confused with mathematical compare operator. Unfortunately there was not left arrow character available during development of programming languages. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to the assignment operator, `p <- 0` in python is expressed as `p = 0`.